# Linux MINT20 "Ulyana" doesn't keep PS1 root setting

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, linux-mint, settings

This that follow is my current PS1 setting in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;36m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;36m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\] '
fi
```

It works ok only for normal user and not for root, why? It always returns to me PS1=`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the prompt after `su` has `/home/maxdm` instead of `~`, it indicates the `su` command probably changed the value of the `HOME` environment variable to the root user's home directory, `/root`.

That means the shell started as root by the `su` command did execute `/root/.bashrc` instead of `/home/maxdm/.bashrc`. So your custom PS1 setting did not get executed.

If you don't want to have per-user `.bashrc` files by default, you can just delete the file or move it to another name. If you want to do it for all existing users on the system, this one-liner will do it:

```
for userhome in $(cut -d : -f 6 /etc/passwd); do [ -f $userhome/.bashrc ] && mv $userhome/.bashrc $userhome/bashrc.disabled; done
```

To stop the `.bashrc` being automatically added for new users you might create later, just remove or rename the file in the new users' home directory template, `/etc/skel`:

```
mv /etc/skel/.bashrc /etc/skel/bashrc.disabled
```

Blocking the ability of the users to have a customized `.bashrc` of their own is not a common request: usually the contents of user's `.bashrc` are considered the user's business, not system administrator's. But if you need to do it for some reason, placing an empty file as `.bashrc` and setting it immutable (`chattr +i .bashrc`) should do the trick.

(Note that this also prevents `userdel -r` from deleting the user's home directory unless you undo the immutability first.)

Comment: How can I to unsource `~/.bashrc` (for booth root and average user) and keep `/etc/bash.bashrc` as the only one system wide file setting?

Comment: Please see my edit above.